# WCF Duplex Service blocking other service calls

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I have a Silverlight application that uses a WCF duplex service (*Service1*) using a [`pollingDuplexHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.pollingduplexhttpbinding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) binding and a polling window of 15 seconds.

I have another service (*Service2*) which is a pretty standard `basicHttpBinding`, hosted on the same domain.

The problem that I am having is that calls to *Service2* time out. This only happens when *Service1* is active. There is basically a permanent connection to *Service1* and it looks like Silverlight, or the hosting browser (Firefox 4, in my tests), can't make a call to *Service2* while polling on *Service1*.

I know that browsers topically limit the number of simultaneous connections to a domain, but 1 seems a bit low?

[image: Firebug Timeline]